# How to approach MySQL result set filters with GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create some of the useful search filters which include a count of the subset that would be filtered once an option is selected. However, with a fairly large data table, I suspect my queries are highly inefficient. I'm not sure what other strategies there may be to approach this.

```
id | color | size
 1 | Red   | Small
 2 | Blue  | Large
 3 | Green | Large
 4 | Blue  | Small
 5 | Red   | Small
 6 | Red   | Small
```

I have 8 attribute columns (such as color, size, type) with 500k plus records in the table.

I'm trying to create "filters" something like:

```
  SELECT `color`, COUNT(`color`)
    FROM `table`
GROUP BY `color`
ORDER BY `color`
```

And would result with something like.

```
Blue  (2)
Green (1)
Red   (3)

Large (2)
Small (4)
```

Then, once someone chooses one of the filters, such as the Small (4), then we need to add a WHERE size = Small, then it would have something like.

```
  SELECT `color`, COUNT(`color`)
    FROM `table`
   WHERE `size` = 'Small'
GROUP BY `color`
ORDER BY `color`

Blue (1)
Red  (3)
```

But, this starts to run incredibly slowly. I assume it's because the group by, order by, probably creates temp tables? Plus, a different query must be run for each filter block. The SELECT `color` for the color filters, and SELECT `size` for the size filters. Which leads to 8 of these groupby/orderby queries run on a 500k data table. Is there a better approach to this?

One catch is, the result set is changing all the time, so even caching for 5 minutes could have fairly out of date result counts.

Also, please let me know if there's some extra data that I need to provide to help develop an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

It will increase its performace by adding an `Index` on column `color` and another on column `size`.

```
CREATE INDEX size_index ON tableName (size);
CREATE INDEX color_index ON tableName (color);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD INDEX size_index (size);
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD INDEX color_index (color);
```

Comment: Thanks John. I do have indexes.